# Disable clickable events

Tags: wordpress, fullcalendar

I am a programming neophyte; please be kind.  I'm using the WP FullCalendar plugin (wordpress.org/plugins/wp-fullcalendar) to create a scheduling calendar for a volunteer ambulance.  The calendar is working fine.  However, I don't want any of the calendar events to be clickable.  I have searched the plugin settings and haven't found anything to disable.  Please let me know which file needs to be changed and what to change it to.  Many, many thanks.  I should add this is being used in a WordPress cms.

Comment: Is this a wordpress plugin?

Comment: Yes, FullCalendar is a WordPress plugin.

Comment: FullCalendar is a jQuery plugin, that somebody wrapped into a WP plugin. Is this the one? https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-fullcalendar/

Comment: in event object you can define true or false to editable field.
[editable](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)

Comment: Thanks, Henrique.  I guessed that might be the spot, but I still don't know where to make that simple change!

Comment: There are multiple wordpress plugins that use fullcalendar. https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=fullcalendar. Which one is it? Tell me which one, and I can tell you if its a setting you can configure or value you have to change in a file.

Comment: Thank you, @MarCrazyness.  It is the jQuery plugin by Adam Arshaw called WP FullCalendar.  You have the correct link.  In spite of my negative review (!), I have researched this.  No direct answers, though similar questions.

Comment: @HenriqueC. this WP Plugin defaults editable field to false. The issue is that the event has a url which is making it clickable. I can't find anything in the options to disable this. I am close to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

After discussing with @clpix, there is not a setting to disable clickable events using the wordpress plugin.

This is a workaround, I would suggest contacting the author and suggesting this as a feature.

Add this to the fullcalendar wp-content/plugins/wp-fullcalendar/wp-fullcalendar.php to the fullcalendar_args. In the latest release I added to line 324 after the comma. The comma is important so please include.

```
eventClick: function(event) {
   return false;
},
```

Comment: Thank you.  It works perfectly.  You are so great to help a complete stranger.  You are right, it should be a setting.